# Puede haber dos onActivityResult en la misma clase de Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Tengo que subir dos imágenes (no tienen que ser subidas al mismo tiempo) a dos `ImageView` , cada una seleccionada por separado de la galería. He conseguido que aparezca una de ellas, pero me duplica los datos en las dos `ImageView` por culpa del `onActivityResult` y me preguntaba como podría dividir el código para que, o aparezcan dos `onActivityResult` o en el mismo, o llamarlo desde otro lado para que llame a dos métodos diferentes.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

`private void openGallery(){
       Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, data);
        if(ResultCode==RESULT_OK && RequestCode==PICK_IMAGE){
            imaginiUri=data.getData();
            imagenInicio.setImageURI(imaginiUri);
            imagfinUri=data.getData();
            imagenFin.setImageURI(imagfinUri);
        }
    }`

Donde `imagenFin` es la `ImageView`

Comment: Osea, quieres que segun la imagen seleccionada se ejecute un codigo o el otro?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que preguntas, por favor, edita tu pregunta y hazla más clara para que podamos echarte una mano. Pero si no me equivoco lo que tienes que hacer es diferenciar de donde vienes a través del parámetro ResultCode, que le das valor antes de volver de la actividad, así sabes de donde vienes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza un `requestCode` diferente según el `ImageView` que quieres actualizar

```
private void openGallery(int requestCode){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, requestCode);
}
```

Y luego en `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_INI){
            imaginiUri=data.getData();
            imagenInicio.setImageURI(imaginiUri);
            return;
        }else if (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_FIN){
            imagfinUri=data.getData();
            imagenFin.setImageURI(imagfinUri);
            return;
        }
    } 

    super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, data);
}
```

No. No puedes tener dos `onActivityResult()` ya que es un método heredado de `Activity`. Cuando la activity secundaria termina, el sistema llama a `Activity.onActivityResult`, y esta a su vez al metodo marcado con `@Override` en tu implementacion, en caso de que exista.

Answer (score 2):

> Puede haber dos onActivityResult en la misma clase de Android?

**NO!**

¿Si sobreescribes el método en varias ocasiones a cual tendría que acceder?,

```
Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
...
...
...
}
```

**lo que se realiza es que el `requestCode` y `resultCode` tenga diferente Id para poder identificar las acciones.**

En cuanto a :

> "He conseguido que aparezca una de ellas, pero me duplica los datos en
>   las dos ImageView por culpa del onActivityResult"

En realidad estas obteniendo el mismo dato para `imaginiUri` y `imagfinUri`

```
    imaginiUri=data.getData();
    imagenInicio.setImageURI(imaginiUri);
    imagfinUri=data.getData();
    imagenFin.setImageURI(imagfinUri);
```